# Wget occasionally failed to download some file

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I'm using the following command to download some file in another machine.
It works fine when the file size of senselist.txt is small(<1G maybe, no accurate number just a estimate).

*When the file size grow bigger, it failed to download one of the  senselist.txt.*

```
wget -r -N -l inf -nd -np -q --accept=senselist.txt* \
     -t 30 -T 60 -c --limit-rate=100M   \
     ftp://ftp:ftp@hostname/home/work/data/20150922 \
     -P  ./data_tmp/20150921000000/tmp_dir
```

Currently there are eight files on the source machine. Sometimes, I failed to download senselist.txt4. But it can't be reproduced, it happens occasionally.
How to fix this, or how to find the reason for this?

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root         1.4G Sep 21 19:04 senselist.txt0
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root          100 Sep 21 19:04 senselist.txt0.md5
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root      1019.8M Sep 21 19:33 senselist.txt1
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root          100 Sep 21 19:34 senselist.txt1.md5
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root         1.1G Sep 21 20:42 senselist.txt2
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root          100 Sep 21 20:42 senselist.txt2.md5
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root         1.1G Sep 21 21:25 senselist.txt3
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root          100 Sep 21 21:25 senselist.txt3.md5
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root      1017.0M Sep 21 21:59 senselist.txt4
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root          100 Sep 21 22:00 senselist.txt4.md5
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root       895.2M Sep 21 22:37 senselist.txt5
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root          100 Sep 21 22:38 senselist.txt5.md5
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root         1.2G Sep 21 23:22 senselist.txt6
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root          100 Sep 21 23:22 senselist.txt6.md5
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root         1.2G Sep 21 23:54 senselist.txt7
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root          100 Sep 21 23:54 senselist.txt7.md5
```

---

**UPDATE**

I wrote the command in a shell script, and use the following code:

```
eval "$cmd_str" 2>>$ERRFILE 1>>$LOGFILE
```

Comment: Try adding a `-d` or `--debug` flag to get more detailed output.  When it doesn't work, it should at least give a clue as to why.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. It just failed to download one of the file, but the rest of  files works fine. That's wired.